# How to publish @Timed metrics right after the application startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

Application use Spring Boot 3 (3.2.1).
Application publish Prometheus metrics using Micrometer.
Here is part of pom.xml configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I use `@Timed` (io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed) annotation to publish metrics.
Example:

```java
@Timed(value = "get_all_books", percentiles = 0.95)
public List<Book> getAll() {
  return booksStorage.getAll();
}
```

It's work well but I could see this metrics just after the method will be called at least once.

How can I configure to see these metrics right after the application startup? I mean I want to see these metrics in the `GET /actuator/prometheus` response even if the methods are not called at all. I understand that the values of the metrics will be zeros, but our support team wants to see them anyway.

Comment: why not call that method on application start up ?

Comment: @RyuzakiL because I have a lot of methods which annotated by `@Timed` and I don't want to forget to call each new such methods in the future. I want to find more flexible way to publish this metrics after startup.